# How do I get the same result returned every time?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Could anyone of you tell me how can I write this function so that I can get the same result every time instead of having the `('nah man')` adding up every time I call `addSomething(myArray)`?

Is this a so called unpure function?

This is a side-effect right?

```js
function addSomething(array) {
  array.push('nah man')
}

let myArray = [1, 2]
addSomething(myArray)
//=> [1, 2, 'nah man']
addSomething(myArray)
//=> [1, 2, 'nah man', 'nah man']
```

Comment: You mean you want to return a new array without changing the original?

Comment: `array.concat('nah man')`

Comment: Thanks for the advice but I am speaking strictly as in a function. I assume you aren't talking about replacing array.push('nah man') with array.concat('nah man') within the function.

Comment: Yes, replace the body of the function

Answer (score 0):

This happens because arrays are passed by reference and not value so any changes to the array in the function are made to the main array.
Use slice to make this work in the way you want.

```
function addSomething(array) {
array=array.slice();
array.push('nah man');
return array;
};
let myArray = [1, 2];
addSomething(myArray);
//=> [1, 2, 'nah man']
addSomething(myArray);
//=> [1, 2, 'nah man']
```

Comment: Shit that's it. Thanks a lot man. But do you know if what I did was a so called non pure function?

Comment: It was but only because of the argument was an array

Answer (score 0):

Check out my simple example

```js
function addSomething(array) {
  let b = array.slice();
  b.push('nah man');
  
  return b;
}

let myArray = [1, 2];
let newArray1 = addSomething(myArray);
let newArray2 = addSomething(newArray1);

console.log(myArray);
console.log(newArray1);
console.log(newArray2);
```